# :last-of-type Pseudo-Class Not Acting as Expected

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm applying `:last-of-type` to an element that should be as such.  Check out the final `div.info` (that's the bottom information for each article) on http://www.elemovements.com.  Why is it not working?

Comment: please give code as opposed to saying "go to this site and figure it out"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is there a `div` element in the `head` of that page..?

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: @David: There's a `div` because defining images with CSS to me is much better than an `img` tag.  What's the issue?

Comment: I think he's referring to placing display content in the page head rather than the body, but I'm on mobile and can't see the source for myself :)

Comment: That `div` it is is not my natural doing.  It's AddThis injecting code into my page.  Case settled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `:nth-of-type()` family of pseudo-classes only look at an element's *type*, that is, its tag name. They do not filter by your class selector or any other selector.

Therefore, your statements:

> I'm applying `:last-of-type` to an element that is clearly as such. Check out the final `div.info`

Are contradictory. There's a `div.center` after that, making *that* the last `div`, not your `div.info`.

[You cannot currently use CSS selectors to find your last `div.info`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230466/106224); you'll have to resort to adding an extra class and/or using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You're having one of the most common misconceptions about CSS. **CSS is not read left-to-right, but right to left!**

Meaning, the browser will look for `div.info:last-of-type`, so browser will filter elements in the following order:

1. Last element of each type (tag name)
2. Has class of `info`
3. Is a `div`.

Your element does not satisfy these conditions in that order. It may be the last div with class of info, but **no last element has a class of `info`**

Comment: I don't believe the right-to-left ordering applies this way (nor will CSS4 selectors mess it up, @Zeta) - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10108700/106224) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813672/106224), particularly the last paragraph, where it makes it clear that some simple selectors are treated specially, and not everything goes strictly from right to left.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Noted. I guess it's finally time to log off for today before I tell anyone that it's good practice to use `$($);`…

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: That's exactly how it goes. The answers you gave me only approve my answer. Pseudo elements are read first, which narrows down the list of elements to scan significantly. It's done for performance.

Answer (score 0):

This 2 are the same:

`div.info:last-of-type`

`div:last-of-type.info`

The `:last-of-type` is hitting the `div`, not the `.info`, and the `.info` is limiting the found results to `0`.

Another example:

`.section.section-test:last-of-type`

Would actually works like: `.section:last-of-type.section-test`