# CSS selector with class a but not class b

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've tried all sorts of things but I think i'm getting too complicated and even managed to get chrome to hang with my selector. I'm sure theres a simple way to do this

Select `classa` but only when theres no `classb` and ignore the last instance of it

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="classa classb"></div> <!-- Dont Select -->
    <div class="classa"></div>  <!-- Select -->
    <div class="classa"></div>  <!-- Dont select last instance -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe you can do this with CSS3 using the `:not()` selected (example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leereichardt/yuAjn/))

`div.classa:not(.classb):not(:last-child) {}`

However, as you know, not many browser supports this, so Javascript might be an easier way...

Comment: Also, you won't be able to exclude the last `.classa` if it's not the last child. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230416/is-it-possible-using-current-browsers-to-use-pseudo-classes-to-detect-first-and/10230466#10230466

Comment: Yes this is a problem ive been getting testing

Answer (score 6):

```
.classa:not(.classb):not(:last-child) {
    /* rules */
}
```

Tested on Firefox 12, Chrome 19, Safari 5 and Opera 10. Unfortunately it doesn't work on (...guess who?) IE.

Comment: Because you haven't upgraded your IE.

Comment: I tested on IE 9 - doesn't work. Even if it worked, most of people still uses older versions...

Comment: Make sure you're testing in standards mode. IE9 supports these selectors fully, but only in standards mode.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was testing without `<!doctype html>`. It works now

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.classa:not(.classb):first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

This won't work in IE 7 or 8 though.

Comment: This is wrong, because the first child is a `.classa.classb`.

Answer (score 0):

With [CSS3 pseudo classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes):

```
.classa:not(:last-child):not(.classb) {
  // some rules...
}
```