# last-child of div class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I am finishing some Wordpress web page and I want to style (with `CSS`) the roll of entries in the `Posts` page. Wordpress creates this:

```
<div class="entry">
```

There are loads of these elements in the page, to separate them I used border at the bottom of the entry. The problem is that I don't want this border on the last entry. Can be anything like that done in CSS? (Note that it's not a list so I can't use pseudo-classes)

Here's my CSS, it's pretty simple:

```
.entry{  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <br />
  there are loads of code
  <br />
  <div class="entry">bunch of code there</div>
  <br />
  <div class="entry">bunch of code there</div>
  <br />
  <div class="entry">bunch of code there</div>
  <br />
  another huge code
  <br />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why can't you use pseudo-classes?

Comment: It would be great if you yould show a part of the HTML-structure and how the `<div class="entry"></div>`-elements are placed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've already named what you're looking for: `last-child`: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild

So use `.entry:not(:last-child) { border-bottom: 1px solid yellow; }`

> Note that it´s not a list so I can´t use pseudo-classes)

JSYK, the pseudoclass does not depend on the containing element being a list. If you meant that the final `.entry` element is not actually the last child of its container, it may still be possible to select it. But I can't tell you how unless you show me what the actual markup looks like.

If your final `div.entry` is not followed by any other divs, then the selector `.entry:not(:last-of-type)` will work for you.

Comment: I guess, as the OP stated, this won't work. It seems, that the entries are not listed after each other within a container.

Comment: I thought he didn't mean a list per se, but a listing of `<div>`s in a single container where `:last-child` would work. But maybe I got it wrong. :)

Comment: It is currently not possible to select the last element of a certain class using only a CSS selector, without making assumptions about the markup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230416/is-it-possible-using-current-browsers-to-use-pseudo-classes-to-detect-first-and

Comment: No, but if it's `last-of-type`, or if it there is some other particular periphery which allows us to target it, it could still be selected. Depends on the markup!

Comment: But also `last-of-type` means *the last child of its parent that is this element*. But you're right. It's all about the markup.

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn´t work.. Yes, they aren´t listed within any container.

Comment: "they aren't listed within any container" is too ambiguous to be useful. Can you please post the markup?

Comment: If you get rid of the `BR` tags will an `.entry` div become the last child of its container?

Comment: Yes, the last `.entry` is really the last child of that wrapper.

Comment: Then you can use `.entry:not(:last-of-type)`.

Comment: Well, to clear that up, there is another code, after the last `.entry` , so this method doesn´t work..

Answer (score 9):

```
.entry:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Let's say you have a list `<li>` with links `<a>` inside, and you want to get that last `<a>` of the `<li>`'s.
Just use:

```
.entry:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

This will select the last of the `.entry` and target it's link(s)

Comment: But I don´t want to target it´s link(s), I want to border that `.entry` element.

Comment: Then just use the first part? Or did I miss something?

Comment: The you probably have a [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) problem.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple solution:

```
#wrapper :last-child
{
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the most comprehensive browser support, I would recommend using this:

```
.entry { border-bottom: 1px solid yellow; }
.entry:last-child { border-bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: This is no different in browser support from `.entry:not(:last-child)`.

Comment: @BoltClock True, but Kevin's way will have borders on all the elements on non supporting browsers, rather than none, which is probably pereferable

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, but it depends on what OP wants to have as degredation using this method. All, or None.

Comment: Of note, just to note it if someone comes across this and it helps; while :not and :last-child share the exact same browser support, :first-child has a little more (ie8 supports :first-child, but does not support :not or :last-child). Just in case someone is head scratching why :last-child and :not don't work the same as :first-child in ie8.