# last child selector in div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and 3 divs inside it. I want to hide the last child div. I tried using `last-child` CSS selector, but it is not working.

The order of divs:

```
<div class="wysibb-toolbar">
    <div class="wysibb-toolbar-container"></div>
    <div class="wysibb-toolbar-container"></div>
    <div class="wysibb-toolbar-container">//(This is to be made display:none)
        <div class="wysibb-toolbar-btn wbb-code" jQuery110208619481903000815="71"></div>
        <div class="wysibb-toolbar-btn wbb-code" jQuery110208619481903000815="71"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
div.wysibb-toolbar div:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your CSS property. It's `display`, not `disply`. If that fixes your problem, I'd recommend deleting your question to avoid downvotes/question closure. If it doesn't fix your problem, then we'll need to see more code, because `display: none;` works for me with that HTML.

Comment: Ah, Sorry corrected the type. But still this is not working

Comment: are you sure those is your real markup?

Comment: yes Fabrizio, copied the markup from developer tool. 
 
I dont have access to HTML file which generated the Jquery or the UI. Can just modify the UI by overriding the classes using css file.So looking for another alternative..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [last-child of div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959655/last-child-of-div-class)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
div.wysibb-toolbar>div:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

or just

```
div.wysibb-toolbar-container:last-child{
 display:none;
}
```

or More generic

```
div.wysibb-toolbar>div.wysibb-toolbar-container:last-child{
 display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have mis-typed the word `display` and have spelt it `disply`

Try this out

```css
div.wysibb-toolbar div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wysibb-toolbar">
  <div class="wysibb-toolbar-container">Test 1</div>
  <div class="wysibb-toolbar-container">Test 2</div>
  <div class="wysibb-toolbar-container">Test 3 (should be hidden)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like that was just a typo; OP has since edited his question to add the missing "a".

Comment: Corrected the typo. Still not working. the last div has two divs inside genrated by jquery. Updated the code. Is the code failing due to jquery? Sorry If am being too naive.

Comment: I dont have access to HTML file which generated the Jquery or the UI. Can just modify the UI by overriding the classes using css file.So looking for another alternative...

Answer (score 0):

:last-child selector matches every element that is the **last child of its parent**.Try this [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8q9g5wj/1/)

```
 .wysibb-toolbar-container:last-child {
    display:none; 
  }
```