# Selecting all rows but the last of class with CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select all  elements in the rows of a certain class except the last row of that class. I have been trying to figure out the correct syntax to do so, but I just can't figure it out.

Here is the CSS I was thinking would do the job:

```
tr.ListRow:not(:last-of-type) td {
    padding: 14px;
    border-bottom-color: #768ca5;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Here is the HTML so you can get an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="Row ListRow">..........</tr> <!-- CSS applied to <td> tags within -->
    <tr class="Graph">..........</tr> 
    <tr class="AltRow ListRow">........</tr> <!-- CSS applied to <td> tags within -->
    <tr class="Graph">..........</tr> 
    <tr class="Row ListRow">..........</tr> <!-- CSS applied to <td> tags within -->
    <tr class="Graph">..........</tr> 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <tr class="AltRow ListRow">........</tr> <!-- CSS NOT applied to this last row of class ListRow -->
    <tr class="Graph">..........</tr> 
</tbody>
```

**Edit: I ended up going a javascript route in which I answered below.**

Comment: `.xyz:last-child` will not fetch all elements with the class of `xyz` then find the last one in that set, it's the other way around, it will grab the last child then if that has a class of `xyz` it will match. Same goes for :last-of-type, nth-child and all the rest. So there's no way to find the last element with a certain class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since others pointed out this is not possible with a single selector, I opted to use jQuery to accomplish this task.

```
function RemoveLastRowBotBorder() {
    var rows = $(".ListRow");
    $(rows[rows.length - 1]).removeClass("ListRow");
}
```

Comment: You could possibly do this with a *jQuery selector* though: `tr.ListRow:last` - unless you have multiple `tbody` or `thead` or `tfoot` elements in which case it gets a little more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to select the last occurring element of a given class, or all elements of a class except the last one, using CSS. `:last-of-type` won't work here because it means "the last `tr` element", not "the last element that matches this compound selector", and your last `tr.ListRow` is not the last `tr`.

The nature of sibling combinators makes it possible to [use an override rule for the *first* element of a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107). However this is not doable for the *last* one.

You're going to have to add a special class to the last `tr.ListRow`, like `Last`, and select `tr.ListRow:not(.Last)`, or find a different way around this.

See also: [Is it possible using current browsers to use pseudo-classes to detect first and last of a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230416/is-it-possible-using-current-browsers-to-use-pseudo-classes-to-detect-first-and/10230466#10230466)

Comment: It's probably good to note that ":not" does not work on IE as of yet.

Comment: Indeed, although "as of yet" is no longer accurate - IE already supports it beginning from version 9, which has been out for a while. Also, if a question is asking specifically about CSS3 selectors it's usually safe to assume that IE support is irrelevant. Many of the selectors mentioned in the question don't work on IE < 9 either.

Comment: Agreed. Always seem to forget people are still using IE8 and below. Such a sad, sad world.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in following way

css

```
.link td {
    background-color:#066;
}
tr.link:last-child td{
    background-color: lime;
}
```

html

```
<table width="200" border="1"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="link">
    <td align="center" valign="middle">2 with Link Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="link">
    <td align="center" valign="middle">4 with Link Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="link">
    <td align="center" valign="middle">6 with Link Class</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

check the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/fU7uP/)